Adjust spacing within tcb theorem and between paragraphs
For reference this is my current tcbtheorem block
\newtcbtheorem[number within=section, list inside = theoremlist, list type = thrm]{thrm}{Theorem}%
{enhanced, breakable,
colback=r!7, colbacktitle=r!17, coltitle=RedViolet,
frame hidden, parbox=false,
arc=1.85pt, titlerule=0pt, toptitle=2pt, bottomtitle=2pt,
fonttitle=\bfseries,separator sign= : \hspace{0.005cm},
segmentation style={solid, draw=r!55, line width=1pt},
before upper=\csname @nobreakfalse\endcsname, halign=left
}{th}

How can I make it so that the spaces between paragraphs is larger, in this environment and in the document in general. And how can I make the space between the tcbline and the proof smaller.

Here is some tester code
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}


\newtcbtheorem[number within=section, list inside = theoremlist, list type = thrm]{thrm}{Theorem}%
{enhanced, breakable,
colback=Red!7, colbacktitle=Red!17, coltitle=Black,
frame hidden, parbox=false,
arc=1.85pt, titlerule=0pt, toptitle=2pt, bottomtitle=2pt,
fonttitle=\bfseries,separator sign= : \hspace{0.005cm},
segmentation style={solid, draw=Red!55, line width=1pt},
before upper=\csname @nobreakfalse\endcsname, halign=left
}{th}


\begin{document}
Testing out the spacing.

Hello. 

\begin{thrm}{Test}{}
His

this is a test 

\tcbline
\begin{proof}
Test

This is not enough space between lines.
\end{proof}
\end{thrm}
\end{document}


Please provide a small compilable example that demonstrates what you are getting now.  Then potential helpers won't have to create their own test file, which might differ from what you're using.

I have added some starter code which shows my issue.

If you use environment lower=proof the extra space goes away. To add space between paragraphs and remove the indent, use the parskip package.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems,skins,breakable}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{parskip}

\newtcbtheorem[
  number within=section,
  list inside = theoremlist,
  list type = thrm
  ]{thrm}{Theorem}%
  {
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    colback=Red!7,
    colbacktitle=Red!17,
    coltitle=Black,
    frame hidden,
    parbox=false,
    arc=1.85pt,
    titlerule=0pt,
    toptitle=2pt,
    bottomtitle=2pt,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    separator sign= : \hspace{0.005cm},
    segmentation style={solid, draw=Red!55, line width=1pt},
    before upper=\csname @nobreakfalse\endcsname,
    halign=left,
    environment lower=proof,
  }{th}


\begin{document}
Testing out the spacing.

Hello. 

\begin{thrm}{Test}{}
\kant[1][1-2]
\kant[2][1-2]
\tcblower
\kant[3][1-2]
\kant[4][1-2]
Closing text.
\end{thrm}

\end{document}


